# Rails 3 and Full Text Search (acts-as-tsearch) on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, full-text-search, heroku

I'm trying to install acts-as-tsearch on heroku. 
I dont want to use any of their two options (IndexTank or Websolr) as they are very costly.

Their home page suggests adding the gem with

```
 ruby script/plugin install git://github.com/pka/acts_as_tsearch.git
```

My app is a rails3 app and that will not work.

I also tried to edit my Gemfile with:

```
gem 'acts_as_tsearch', :git => 'git://github.com/pka/acts_as_tsearch.git'
```

and Im getting:

```
Could not find gem 'acts_as_tsearch (>= 0)' in git://github.com/pka/acts_as_tsearch.git (at master).
Source does not contain any versions of 'acts_as_tsearch (>= 0)'
```

Has anyone managed to install Acts as tsearch on heroku ?

Any other options ?

Comment: Another option is (my own) acts_as_indexed. Minimal setup and configuration. Works on Heroku. https://github.com/dougal/acts_as_indexed

Comment: Your plugin does exactly was is supposed to!
PERFECT! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indextank has changed their pricing scheme, it's free up to 100K documents. (I'm one of IndexTank's developers)